# tf2 How to generate rotation matrix from axis-angle rotation?

Tags: ros, transform, ros-indigo, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a build-in `tf2` functionality where we can generate a rotation matrix given an axis (`tf2::Vector3`) and an angle (`double`). E.g.
Suppose you have:

```
tf2::Vector3 vec(2,3,4); // by axis I mean - any - axis, not just x,y,z
double angle_rads=1.57;
tf2::Matrix3x3 rotation_matrix(vec,rads); // <-- is there an easy way like this?
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295134/tf2-how-to-generate-rotation-matrix-from-axis-angle-rotation?/) by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2018-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK found it my self :) For people that are wondering (it goes through Quaternions):

```
tf2::Quaternion q;
q.setRotation(rot_vec,angle);
tf2::Matrix3x3 R(q);
```

---

Originally posted by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) with karma: 97 on 2018-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3